# I already have a GameManager script, but need to have a 2nd one

Tags: unity, c#, visual-studio

I'm making a Unity game, and I want to use the Unity Distribution Portal.

My problem is that you have to make a script named `GameManager` for this, but I already have another script called `GameManager`, so every time I try to rename the first `GameManager` script, the game stops working.

I don't want to rewrite every script I've used `GameManager` variables in. So the way I've been trying to rename this is by right-clicking on the `GameManager.cs` file in the Unity project window and renaming it there, then typing a 2 in the name inside Visual Studio.

If I call the script for UDP for example something like `GameManager2`, UDP doesn't seem to understand that this is the script it needs for Sandbox Testing.

Can anyone help me with this?

Here is the UDP script I want to add (which is currently called `GameManager2`, but needs to be called `GameManager`):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UDP;

public class InitListener : MonoBehaviour, IInitListener
{
    public IInitListener listener;
    public void Start()
    {
        StoreService.Initialize(listener);
    }

    public void OnInitialized(UserInfo userInfo)
    {
        Debug.Log("Initialization succeeded");    
    }

    public void OnInitializeFailed(string message)
    {
        Debug.Log("Initialization failed: " + message);
    }
}
```

Comment: The script code you've included in the question has no reference to a `GameManager` at all. Are you sure that's the code that's giving you trouble?

Comment: I think so... Or do you need a different code for doing Sandbox Testing... then please tell me!

Comment: What a timely question, so thank for telling me something I needed to know. I was considering using UDP with my next project, and I have a class with the almost conflicting name GameController, so I should be careful! although I use namespaces so maybe I would've been fine anyway...

Answer (score 1):

When you just type a new name in a class, that doesn't change all the other code files that are trying to refer to that class's name. So you'll get all kinds of compiler errors because they're now referring to a name that doesn't exist.

Instead, you should right-click on the identifier you want to change, and select Rename (or press F2 as a shortcut)

[image: Rename option]

Instances of that name will be highlighted in green, and will all be updated in-sync as you modify the name. A box in the corner will tell you how many references in how many files are going to be changed (and warn you of any conflicts).

[image: Renaming in progress]

When you're happy with the new name, click Apply or press Enter to accept the change and save all the files modified in the process.

Do this before adding the Unity Distribution Portal content to your project, to be sure you don't accidentally mess up any of its references to its own Game Manager script.

I'd also recommend choosing a more informative name than `GameManager2` - maybe `LocalGameManager` or `PongGameManager` (if you're making a "Pong" game), etc. Something that will remind you in 6 months which file is "your" version of the game manager and which one you got from the distribution portal guide.

Comment: Thank you... but now it shows me multiple (20) **"The type or namespace name '...' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"** and **"The type or namespace name '...' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"** messages

Comment: It sounds like you accidentally renamed something "...", which is not a valid identifier.

Comment: Things that are between the "..." are: UDP, IInitListener, UserInfo, ILicencingListener, LicensingCode, LicensingErrorCode, IPurchaseListener, PurchaseInfo & Inventory... How can you make the errors disapear by using those? I´ve definitely not renamed them!

Comment: Sounds like an unrelated problem. Your code might be missing a `using` statement to tell the compiler where to find those items, or you might not have correctly imported the UDP scripts into your project.

Comment: I´ve used the `using`, so I´m going delete (or downdate) all files i´ve done something during the UDP progress, reimport UDP through the Assets store and then i´ll question again, what to do next.

Comment: I´ve now reimported UDP (No Red Errors) connected the Game in Unity Engine with the Project on the UDP Website and now i don´t know whether to make a new script with the code showed in the question, and what to do then... (and if yes, how should i call it, or doesn´t this matters?)

Comment: Again, this sounds like a different question than "how can I rename my existing GameManager to avoid conflicts". You can create a new Question post if you'd like help with this.